# Why json_decode doesn't work?

Tags: php, jquery

can somebody tell me where I'm making the error in the following code? I want to read the title of the 1 Position in the json Array.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loading').click(function(){
            var NpPData = [
    {
        "title": "Professional JavaScript",
        "author": "Nicholas C. Zakas"
    },
    {
        "title": "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
        "author": "David Flanagan"
    },
    {
        "title": "High Performance JavaScript",
        "author": "Nicholas C. Zakas"
    }
];
            var NpPDataJSON = JSON.stringify(NpPData);
            alert(NpPDataJSON);
            $.post("prueba.php", NpPDataJSON, function(r){
                    $('#result').html('Answer from server: '+r);
                }, 
            'json').error(function(e){
                alert('FAiled: '+e.statusText);
            });
        });

      });
    </script>
```

And PHP:

```
$json = $_POST['NpPDataJSON'];
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[1]['title'];
```

Comment: Have you tried `{NpPDataJSON: NpPDataJSON}` in the `$.post` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Set second parameter to `TRUE` to have [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to return an `array` instead of an `stdClass` object:

```
$json = $_POST['NpPDataJSON'];
$data = json_decode($json, true); // note the second argument 
echo $data[1]['title']; // returns 'JavaScript: The Definitive Guide'
```

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

---

Also, as per [@Stryner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3900153/stryner)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588394/why-json-decode-doesnt-work/32588424?noredirect=1#comment53031098_32588394), it seems you have misused the [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function. You need to set a name to the data you are passing to the server and therefore, pass an object instead of a variable:

```
$.post("prueba.php", {NpPDataJSON: NpPDataJSON}, function(r){/* ... */}, 'json');
```

Comment: Thx! I did it, but is not working :( I don't get the result that I expect

Comment: What result do you get and what result do you expect?

Comment: I Change the php code to this: $json = $_POST['NpPDataJSON'];
$data = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($data);
echo json_encode($data[1]['title']); is not working :(

Comment: Why are you reencoding your data??

Comment: what you mean with reencoding? I am sorry for the question. I am really new in the subject

Comment: Again: *What result do you get and what result do you expect?*.

Comment: I don't have enough Points for a Chat :( I want to get the title of the book in the second Position of the books Array. THX!

Comment: And *what result do you get instead*?

Comment: I am getting the message from the error function of the jquery side: Failed: OK. That means Status OK, but why is not doing what I want? :(

Comment: I mean the result from the **PHP function** you are using.

Comment: my PHP function doesn't Returns nothing is like dead :(

Comment: How I should send the result that I want back to the Client (jquery)

Comment: No, is not working I tried {NpDataJSON: NpPDataJSON} in the post() Statement, but also the same Problem. :(

Comment: "*not working*" is **not** a problem description. Please be specific or else no-one will be able to help you here. **What problem are you facing?**

Comment: @D4V1D It's `NpPDataJSON` instead of `NpDataJSON`. That might be the issue.